# How to change project's C++ standard after creating it in CLion?

Tags: c++, clion

Is it possible to change the C++ standard for a project (which was selected at the time of creating it) after creating it? If yes, how?

I want to change the standard used for a project from C++17 to C++11.

Comment: You can change the project flags from `-std=c++17` to `-std=c++11`

Comment: If you created a project using CMake, there is a file `CMakeLists.txt`. You can edit this file.